# how to place the equation number in the right

Tags: equations, numbering, positioning

I wrote the equations and I manage to align the regression, but the numbers are showing below the regression. How can I align it in the right?

this is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{reg5}
\begin{align}

\begin{small}PRODUCTION_{i,t} = b_0 + b_1FORECAST_{i,t} + b_2PEER\_FORECAST_{i,t} + 

b_3FORECAST_{i,t} * CEO\_TURNOVER_{t-1}  + 

b_4PEER\_FORECAST_{i,t} * CEO\_TURNOVER_{t-1}  + b_5UNEMP_{t-1} + 

b_6HORIZON_t\end{small}                                                                          
\end{align}
\end{equation}
```

Can someone help me with this one?

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on Werner’s answer (with compliments to his crystal ball… :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % not actually necessary, but recommended
\usepackage[width=14cm]{geometry} % just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Text before.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \text{PRODUCTION}_{i,t} &=
            b_0 + b_1 \text{FORECAST}_{i,t} + b_2 \text{PEER\_FORECAST}_{i,t} \\
            &\qquad + b_3 \text{FORECAST}_{i,t} \times \text{CEO\_TURNOVER}_{t-1} \\
            &\qquad + b_4 \text{PEER\_FORECAST}_{i,t} \times \text{CEO\_TURNOVER}_{t-1} \\
            &\qquad + b_5 \text{UNEMP}_{t-1} + b_6 \text{HORIZON}_t
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

(after seeing the output, I decided that I prefer `\qquad` over `\quad`).
Here is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

---

## Addition

With @egreg’s suggestions, the code becomes

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % not actually necessary, but recommended
\usepackage[width=14cm]{geometry} % just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Text before.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \text{PRODUCTION}_{i,t} =
            b_0 &+ b_1\,\text{FORECAST}_{i,t} + b_2\,\text{PEER\_FORECAST}_{i,t} \\
            &+ b_3\,\text{FORECAST}_{i,t} \times \text{CEO\_TURNOVER}_{t-1} \\
            &+ b_4\,\text{PEER\_FORECAST}_{i,t} \times \text{CEO\_TURNOVER}_{t-1} \\
            &+ b_5\,\text{UNEMP}_{t-1} + b_6\,\text{HORIZON}_t
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

which gives the following output:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

Comment: In this particular case, the alignment point should be the plus sign. I'd also experiment a thin space between the coefficient ant the ”textual“ variables.

Comment: @egreg: I had thought of both possibilities, but I was unsure: your advice is therefore valuable.  **Off-topic:** please accept my apologies for the somewhat rude reply that I gave you yesterday.  I understand your point of view about that—pretty silly, I must admit—`\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}` line.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \text{PRODUCTION}_{i,t} &= b_0 + b_1 \text{FORECAST}_{i,t} + b_2 \text{PEER\_FORECAST}_{i,t} + \nonumber \\
    &\phantom{{}={}} b_3 \text{FORECAST}_{i,t} \times \text{CEO\_TURNOVER}_{t-1} + \nonumber \\
    &\phantom{{}={}} b_4 \text{PEER\_FORECAST}_{i,t} \times \text{CEO\_TURNOVER}_{t-1} + b_5 \text{UNEMP}_{t-1} + \nonumber \\
    &\phantom{{}={}} b_6 \text{HORIZON}_t
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Some problems with your code:

- You can't use an `align` inside `equation`;
- Don't leave blank lines inside `align`;
- Don't us text-related font scaling inside math mode (like `\small`);
- `small` is technically not an environment.

Numbering can be suppressed for `align` using `\nonumber`.

Comment: Just for completeness it might be faster to write `= {}  & ` in stead of `&=` in the first line, and just `&` in subsequent lines

Comment: @daleif: Good suggestion.